# Complicated string extraction in java

Tags: java, regex

I am working with a diff library in java that outputs diffs with square brackets around them where multiple diffs of the same type exist and no square brackets for diffs where only one diff exists.

An example of the multiple diff is "Diff(4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS ], [ )" and "Diff(2, R43,R46, 51k ], [ 2, R44,R47, 10k ], [ 2, R45,R48, 1k ], [ )". Examples of the single diffs are "Diff(PBSS306NZ,135)" and "Diff(4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS ], [ )".

I am looking to extract the diffs from the strings like "4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS" instead of "Diff(4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS ], [ )" and I have looked at some of the questions on here that try to do something similar but the regex in those questions dont do what I need.  I tried "\[[^\]]*\]" and "\[.*?\]+" but they dont work. Any help from the regex experts will be appreciated.

I have uploaded a sample output file at https://rapidshare.com/#!download|869l36|460197924|regextest.txt|1

Comment: Hmmm... I had a look at that Diff file. Question: Which is the first-order bracket () or []? It's just that I can't see the logic in the format, and I'm wondering if it's me, or if it's just a really messy format... and I'm loath to suggest using a lexical-parser if the format isn't well-formed (i.e. it isn't lexical;-).

Comment: @corlettk Exactly my thoughts. Trying to find a method to this randomness myself. Very interesting problem otherwise :)

Comment: I think I see what you mean, from the file output its not very clear but the first diff is 3 lines long and the file delimiter is a newline char. the first order bracket is ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernard,

Regarding your additional question in the comment on WhiteFang34's most excellent answer.

## www.regular-expressions.info

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is THE most **regilicious web-resource** on the planet.
They cover ALL things regex, with correct, accessible explanations of detailed worked **examples**...

In many cases there coverage is better than the authors original documentation (especially true of Java, sadly). And they cover **all languages** which support regular expressions, impartially.

Also: Checkout there Tools section: They've got an interactive regex testerpator. *USE IT* any time you need to develop a non-superficial regex. Think "IDE for Regex's". It's magic (IMHO). And I've just discovered there automatic regex-generator, which seems to even sort-of work.

Anyway, the site is a god-send, just for the clarity of there explanations.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does what you're looking for:

```
File file = new File("regextest.txt");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    line = line.replaceAll("^Diff\\(", "");
    line = line.replaceAll("\\)$", "");
    sb.append(line);
}
String combined = sb.toString();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(combined);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String extract = combined.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    extract = extract.replaceAll("\\[ ?", "");
    extract = extract.replaceAll(" ?\\]", "");
    System.out.println(extract);
}
```

For your `regextest.txt` file the output looks like:

```
12, C1,C4,C5,C6,C9,C10,C15,C18,C19,C20,C23,C24, C0603, 10nF
10, C2,C3,C7,C8,C13,C16,C17,C21,C22,C27, C0603, 100nF
2, C11,C25, SMT, 1uF LOW ESR 50V
4, C12,C14,C26,C28, C0805, 2u2
4, D1,D2,D4,D9, SOT23, BAS40-04/SOT
4, D3,D5,D6,D7, SMB, SMBJ5.0A
1, D8, SMB, SMBJ15A
2, D10,D11, SMB, SMBJ30A
1, J1, SMT, CON12
2, L1,L2, SMT, 744043471, 470uH
4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS
...
```

Comment: Nice! Please could you explain \\[.+?\\] match? I'll have a go, but please correct me if I'm wrong: a '[' then RELUCTANTLY(one-or-more-any-character) then a ']'... is that it? And that's equivalent to "\\[[^\\]]+\\]", but more readable, yeah?

Comment: You're correct, it's a reluctant match that stops at the first `]`. I believe it's equivalent and does seem more readable. However I wasn't thinking about it at the time, that just happens to be what I wrote :)

Comment: WhiteFang34, that works brilliantly, I'm actually quite impressed with how clean that looks! Do you have any web resources you use to learn regex for java that I can take a look at? Cheers again :)

Answer (score 1):

Bernard,

I guess this might contain a few pointers which I guess might get you going along the right track.

```
package forums;

public class RegexTest2
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      final String expected = "4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS";
      String actual = "Diff(4, L3,L4,L5,L6, 119LNS ], [ )"
        .replaceAll("^Diff\\(( \\], \\[ )?", "")
        .replaceAll("[\\[\\], )]*$", "");
      assert expected.equals(actual) : actual;
      //System.out.println("Correct result: "+actual);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Yup, there's a LOT of guessing going on here... because I don't really know WHAT you want to match... and probably more importantly: everything that you want to NOT match.

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:** Now that I think of it, we're using a bomb where a hammer will do... That is: we're trying to use REGEX (a general purpose **pattern** matcher) when all we REALLY want is a simple "remove any-and-all-of-these-characters from the start and end of a string. Surely a "custom" method would be a cleaner approach, even if it's a bit more code.

Comment: Hi corlettk, thanks for the pointers. I had the same thought yesterday about trying to write a simple "remove any-and-all-of-these-characters" and I actually did try going down that route but it opens a whole can of worms because the string do not always have the same endings. The regex test file has an example where the line ends with "[ ] ])" and one that ends with "[ )" and I wanted something that would be robust and handle all permutations. Thats why I thought regex might help. Your solution works as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bernard: My char stripper would be something like:  remove-from-start all characters in "[] ," and remove-from-end all characters in "[] ," ... which would be fairly simple code. It'd just find the index of first "wanted" char, and the last "wanted" char and then return a substring(start, len).